# convert vb.net data to json string and send it to a specific URL

Tags: vb.net, string, json

this is the JSON string the data is required in to be sent using a given URL.

```
$jsonstr = '{"data":
     [{
      "id":"5",
      "owner_id":"0",
      "status":"unassigned",
      "first_name":"Test",
      "last_name":"IS",
      "tobacco_user":"",
      "date_of_birth":"",
      "age":"",
      "gender":"",
      "email":"lb@you.com",
      "zip":"",
      "phone":"(210)629-2560",
      "phone_type":"cell",
      "phone_alt":"",
      "phone_alt_type":"",
      "product_msip":"",
      "product_pdp":"",
      "product_sdhv":""
        },
```

I am using VB.net and i need to create this string using VB.net. I tried using namevaluecollection and doing a POST. I also tried making a string and send data using GET. Both failed. how can i do this?

Answer (score 1):

Create an object with property names that are identical to those in your example, use the [`DataContract`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) and [`DataMember`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute.aspx) attributes to mark serialization.

Then use the [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) to serialize the object into JSON.

> you can use the class when you want to work with JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) in managed code.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to build an actual class as @Oded recommended you can just hack it together as a string. I usually use a NameValueCollection as you said you tried.

```
    ''//Setup some values
    Dim NVC As New NameValueCollection()
    NVC.Add("id", "5")
    NVC.Add("owner_id", "0")
    NVC.Add("status", "unassigned")

    ''//Convert to string
    Dim Pairs As New List(Of String)
    For Each N As String In NVC.Keys
        Pairs.Add(String.Format("""{0}"":""{1}""", N.Replace("""", "\"""), NVC(N).Replace("""", "\""")))
    Next
    Dim S = Join(Pairs.ToArray(), ",")
```

`S` now holds `"id":"5","owner_id":"0","status":"unassigned"` which you should be able to concat into your bigger JSON string.